# Intellitrace XML File

Tags: visual-studio-2012, intellitrace

I'm planning to try and use intellitrace in production and using the pre-configured trace plans it's not helpful and is just using the default stuff. Right now, there is no easy way to edit the intellitrace settings when you want to use it for production so I have to manually edit the XML file as necessary.

I was trying to think of looking for the XML file that Visual Studio is using for its intellitrace settings so that I can see and edit the xml trace plan for production setting. Does anyone know where the file of this XML is stored when editing the settings through Visual Studio, or if it ever have one?

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ianhu/archive/2010/02/10/intellitrace-and-collectionplan-xml.aspx) contains some basic idea on how Collection Plan works for IntelliTrace. Note that for Dev11 and later the collection plan file locates at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\IntelliTrace\12.0.0\en"

When editing Intellitrace settings for F5 inside Visual Studio, the change you made will saved to registry and won't be persist as a XML file once VS is closed. However when you  start F5, a temporary XML file will be generated for IntelliTrace. A hacky way to peek into this file will be using tools like process explorer and check the command line for IntelliTrace process. The command line will be something like:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\IntelliTrace\12.0.0\IntelliTrace.exe" run /name:consoleapplication1.exe_00000be4_01cef44c123dc290_f3a1abc6-5b3a-45e4-83e7-dfbf4275b3e7 /logfile:C:\Windows\Temp\ConsoleApplication1.exe_131208_113120_f3a1abc6-5b3a-45e4-83e7-dfbf4275b3e7.iTrace /buffersize:65536 /buffercount:512 /watch:-1 /help- /nologo+ /collectionplan:**C:\Users\Fangliang\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\TraceDebugger\Settings\yurhq2cv.tah** /hidden-

This command line contains most of the information for current running IntelliTrace. The bold part will be the collection plan you are looking for. However, this isn't an officially supported scenario and there is no promise this settings can be applied to production scenario (though most likely they will work), you will be pretty much on your own to figure out how the rest part works.